# I can't overwrite the OnCreateOptionMenu()

Tags: java, android

I want to create an application that shows me the optionMenu, but when i wanted to overwrite the onCreateOptionMenu, there's no trace of that. I mean I can't see it in the collection of activity class methods!!
Can you help me???

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.optionsmenu"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.derakhshani.optionsmenu.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Why are you posting your xml? Overriding a method is done in java.

Comment: post the class where you want to override it

Comment: i thought that problem is related to my manifest file

Answer (score 1):

Inside your class that extends Activity, you should be able to override it like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Do other stuff here
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: i know i need to these codes when i want to create OptionMenu, but when i try to overwrite that method i mean onCreateOptionsMenu() the eclipse shows me an error.